# Assassin's creed 4 connors robes

Tags: ps3, assassins-creed-4-black-flag

I lately played assassin's creed 4 and was rewarded with Altair and Ezio's robes but i have only played assassin's creed 3 and assassin's creed 2 so i was wondering if i could play assassin's creed liberation get uplay points and rewards and unlock Connor's robes. Would this work or not please help.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the [Assassin's Creed Wiki](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Assassin%27s_Creed_IV:_Black_Flag_outfits):

> **Connor's outfit**
>
> Awarded to those with an internet connection and three Assassin's Creed games in their Uplay rewards and actions.

Since U-Play is checking that the games are logged in your game library, you will need to log in to U-Play from three separate Assassin's Creed games (and from my interpretation, completed at least one of its 'actions').

If the unlock was specifically earned by spending U-play points, earned through completing the actions, then yes. You could earn the points in an unrelated game. U-play points are not specific to the game, so you are free to earn points in one game, and spend them all in a different title.

Answer (score 0):

Connor's robes are awarded to those with an internet connection and three Assassin's Creed games in their Uplay rewards and actions.